# Unable to parse object to the event through API Gateway to get response from Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

Iam new to the serverless development. Iam trying to create a simple rest api using aws Lambda and API Gateway. 
I have following json in my s3 and i want to return the object based on request when the API is invoked

```
{
"customerA":
 {"Age": "29", "Product": "Laptop"},
 "customerB": {
 "Age": "30", 
 "Product": "Mobile" 
}
}
```

Below is the lambda function for which i have added the same API trigger

```
import json
import boto3


def customer(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    resource='s3'
    s3=boto3.resource(resource)
    s3Bucket='mys3'
    bucketKey='customerDetails.json'
    obj=s3.Object(s3Bucket,bucketKey)
    body=obj.get()['Body'].read()
    customer={}
    customer=json.loads(body)
    value={}
    # customerCode is the parameter defined in your serverless.yml
    customerCode = event['custCode']

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(customer[customerCode]),
        'headers': {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

```
service: customer-function

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
  -  Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:ListBucket"
     Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mys3"

  -  Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:PutObject"
       - "s3:GetObject"
       - "s3:DeleteObject"
     Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mys3/*"

functions:
  customer_serverless:
    handler: handler.customer
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
    events:
      - http:
          path: customer_resource/cust_content/
          method: get
```

Expected: What iam looking for is, when i invoke the api with the request  'customerA', the api should return the object for the 'customerA'  : '{"Age": "29", "Product": "Laptop"}'
So how to invoke the API with the request to get the above response as below
when i invoke api
it return all values if iam only calling

```
 "body': json.dumps(customer)"
```

with below api

```
test-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/customer_1/cust-details/
```

but when i invoke with below api

```
test-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/customer_1/cust-details/customerA
```

it throw the key error

My expected result is

```
{"Age": "29", "Product": "Laptop"}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
import json
import boto3


def hello(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    resource='s3'
    s3=boto3.resource(resource)
    s3Bucket='bucketname'
    bucketKey='customer.json'
    obj=s3.Object(s3Bucket,bucketKey)
    body=obj.get()['Body'].read()
    customer={}
    customer=json.loads(body)
    value={}
    # customerCode is the parameter defined in your serverless.yml
    customerCode = event['pathParameters']['customerCode']

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(customer[customerCode]),
        'headers': {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }
```

## serverless.yml

```
service: customer-function

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
  -  Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:ListBucket"
     Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"

  -  Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:PutObject"
       - "s3:GetObject"
       - "s3:DeleteObject"
     Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
    events:
      - http:
          path: customer_1/cust-details/{customerCode}
          method: get
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Arun, thank you for your replay. What iam looking for is to integrate the event request and return the object as below
https://test-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/customer_1/cust-details/customerA
then it should return the response in the body 
'{"Age": "29", "Product": "Laptop"}
I have modified the question.

Comment: i understand it now

Comment: therefore a mistake and i have updated the answer again

Comment: HI @Arun, i still didn't get what to input on 'customerCode = event['pathParameters']['customerCode']' part. can you please give a hint on this?

Comment: The value is `customerA`. Https://test-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/customer_1/cust-details/customerA.    Look at the finishing part of the URL

Comment: The last part of the url which is `customerA` will be available to the code inside `event.pathParameters`.  because if you check the serverless.yml , we have defined it as a parameter in the path by saying `path: customer_1/cust-details/{customerCode`

Comment: Hi @Arun, as you suggested i deployed the code, but while invoking with the url, it returns internal error.
My url is something like this https://test-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/customer_1/cust-details/customerA

What i done so far is, I created a new function, updated the serverless.yaml where i updated the above events part and deployed the same. After i created added a new trigger for the lambda. 
Please let me know what wrong went?

Comment: can you tell me how did you deploy

Comment: Hi Arun, i deployed using the aws cli - sls command . I modified the question with the code and yaml file

Comment: can you do `sls info` and attach the screenshot. if you are doing so make sure to hide the account numbers before posting

Comment: i dont think the deployment worked well, because your api gateway screenshot not including {customerCode} in the end points

Comment: Also you dont need to hardcode the IAM credentials inside the lambda, you can instead assign permissions to your lambda's IAM role

Comment: Hi Arun, can you share me your email id if possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204291/discussion-between-arun-k-and-hanju).

Comment: posted a message for you in the chat

Answer (score 0):

You have configured API Gateway as Lambda Proxy. When you make this configuration, a convention is in place that force your Lambda function to return a JSON object like this:

```
{
    statusCode: 200,
    body: "{\"Age\": \"29\", \"Product\": \"Laptop\"}",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
}
```